# Can STL help addressing memory fragmentation

Tags: c++, windows, memory, stl

This is regarding a new TCP server being developed (in C++ on Windows/VC2010)

Thousands of clients connect and keep sending enormous asynchronous requests. I am storing incoming requests in raw linked list ('C' style linked-list of structures, where each structure is a request) and process them one by one in synchronized threads.

I am using in `new` and `delete` to create/destroy those request structures.

Till date I was under impression its most efficient approach. But recently I found even after all clients were disconnected, **Private Bytes** of server process still showed lots of memory consumption (around 45 MB) It never came back to it's original level.

I dig around a lot and made sure there are no memory leaks. Finally, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916514/why-does-a-processs-private-bytes-memory-counter-never-return-back-to-its-or) and realized its because of memory fragmentation caused of lots of `new` and `delete` calls.

Now my couple of questions are:

1. If I replace my raw linked list with STL data structures to store incoming requests, will it help me getting rid of memory fragmentation ? (Because as per my knowledge STL uses contiguous blocks. Kind of its own memory management resulting in very less fragmentation. But I am not sure if this is true.)
2. What would be performance impact in that case as compared to raw linked list?

Comment: How do you find out the amount of memory used? Windows can keep memory freed by a process, lying around in case it allocates more memory again in the future.

Comment: I use `.PrivateUsage` member of the `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` structure.

Comment: Freed memory isn't necessary returned to system. It may still be owned by the program that originally requested it, but for future reuse of its further allocations (to prevent unnecessary requests to increase heap size).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your main problem is that you are using linked lists.  Linked lists are horrible for this sort of thing and cause exactly the problem you are seeing.  Many years ago, I wrote TCP code that did very similar things, in plain old C.  The way to deal with this is to use dynamic arrays.  You end up with far fewer allocations.

In those bad old days, I rolled my own, which is actually quite simple.  Just allocate a single data structure for some number of records, say ten.  When you are about to overflow, double the size, reallocating and copying.  Because you increase the size exponentially, you will never have more than a handful of allocations, making fragmentation a non-issue.  In addition, you have none of the overhead that comes with list.

Really, lists should almost never be used.

Now in terms of your actual question, yes, the STL should help you, but DON'T use `std:list`.  Use `std:vector` in the manner I just outlined.  In my experience, in 95% of the cases, `std:list` is an inferior choice.

If you use `std:vector`, you may want to use `vector::reserve` to preallocate the number of records you expect you may see.  It'll save you a few allocations.

Comment: You pinpointed my exact pain. `std:list` is out of question as it would not much different than raw list as long as fragmentation is concerned. But between std::vector and std::queue what is better? (Because queue is fifo, fits in the requirement. But not sure how good/bad is it from fragmentation perspective as compared to vectors. Any thoughts please?)

Comment: I don't recall for sure, but I believe the implementation of `vector` and `queue` is essentially identical.

Comment: Ok I'll check on that bit. Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Comment: @StevenBurnap: `std::vector` and `std::queue` are not at all identical. `std::queue` is a container adapter which requires the underlying container to provide a `pop_front()` function which `std::vector` doesn't have. Two containers that satisfy the requirements are `std::deque`, which is the default, and `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen that your memory usage and fragmentation is causing you performance problems?  I would think it is more from doing `new` / `delete` a lot.  STL probably won't help unless you use your own allocator and pre-allocate a large chunk and manage it yourself.  In other words, it will require a lot of work.

It's often OK to use up memory if you have it.  You may want to consider pooling your request structures so you don't need to reallocate them.  Then you can allocate on demand and add them to your pool.

Comment: Fragmentation is not causing performance. But my nightmare is if I kept server running for days, fragmentation will cause in denial of memory allocations (as good as no memory)?

Comment: Based on that, I think you should manage a pool of objects then, and do the dynamic allocation when needed.  Basically once you're done with a request object, stick it in a pool of unused objects.  When you want to "allocate" one, check the unused pool first, and if it's empty, then `new`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe. `std::list` allocates each node dynamically like a homebrew linked list. "STL uses contiguous block.." - this is not true. You could try std::vector which is like an array and therefore will cause less memory fragmentation. Depends on what you need the data structure for.
2. I wouldn't expect any discernable difference in performance between a (well-implemented) homebrew linked list and std::list. If you need a stack, `std::vector` is much more efficient and if you need a queue (eg fifo) then `std::deque` is much more efficient than linked lists.

If you are serious about preventing memory fragmentation, you will need to manage your own memory and custom allocators or use some third party library. It's not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raw pointers you can use std::unique_ptr. It has minimal overhead, and makes sure your pointers get deleted.

In my opinion there are pretty few cases where a linked list is the right choice of data structure. You need to chose your data structure based on the way you use your data. For example using a vector will keep your data together, which is good for cache, if you can manage to add/remove elements to it's end, then you avoid fragmentation.

If you want to avoid the overhead of new/deletes you can pool your objects. This way you still need to handle fragmentation.